# Graphics driver problem for GTX660 Ti

Tags: 12.10, gnome, drivers, nvidia, steam

In the "additional drivers" section of Software Sources it says there is no proprietary drivers in use. I can't seem to find another way to install them, other than downloading them directly from nVidia and installing them myself (which always breaks my system, forcing me to reinstall). I can't even seem to find the Nouveau driver though.

I didn't have this problem with my GTX570.

I am looking for drivers since there is stutter going on in the desktop animations and Steam "Big Picture" mode results in just a black screen.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with the latest version of GNOME + GDM login screen (this was also an issue with Unity, however).

My graphics card is an EVGA GTX660 Ti FTW+ (3 GB RAM) plugged into an ASRock Z77 Pro 3 motherboard.

EDIT: I used the command:

> *sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings*

Now I have Nvidia x-server as an app in my list, but still saying I'm not running any proprietary drivers.

Also, I have two monitors, and when I set it to "Mirror displays" it dropped my resolution to 1024x768 (4:3) and wouldn't let me restore to my previous setting. Now I'm stuck with this annoying aspect ratio... (Before I ticked "Mirror displays" the resolution box already said 1024x768 (4:3) but it looked more like 1920x1080 (16:9)).

EDIT 2: After a complete system lockup and reboot via reset button, Ubuntu won't even boot anymore. It just hangs at a purple screen that usually comes up just before login. This issue has forced me to reinstall several times in the last couple of days. Its possible if I keep rebooting it will work again although this only worked once. This is the first reboot since the resolution changed.

Comment: Same here, stuck with a similar setup. When I install the NVidia drivers compiz and Unity just stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Some info usually can be found in file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: What should I be looking for in there?